# How do you manage namespace in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, javascript-namespaces

So here is my problem :
Currently, I have a dozen of functions related to WEBRTC within a template js file. My objective is to have those functions in a separate file, called webRTCWrapper.js for example, and to call those functions in my template without using global variable.

I think I must use namespaces, am I correct ?
If so, how do you use them ?

EDIT : For anyone interested, this is exactly what I was looking for :

http://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-the-module-pattern-with-meteor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a directory called `packages/` parallel to your `.meteor/` directory. You can create a package that exports a single object/function. On the command line, use `meteor create --package <yourpackagename>` and `meteor add <yourpackagename>` You can edit the js file to add a namespace.

```
MyNamespace = {};
MyNamespace.myFunction = function () { };
```

Then, in the package.js, simply export that namespace.

```
api.export('MyNamespace');
```

Comment: In the specific case of the OP, that is probably the best way since I assume his WebRTC code is to be used as a typical module.

However, if only need to namespace a small portion of your project, like say the posts functions of a forum, then making a package is probably overkill if not damn right confusing. It would make more sense to make a package called forum and then have "package-private"/"internal"/"protected" (what ever you want to call them) objects inside a package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common pattern of having a global object and your functions inside that object.

```
Greetings = {
   hello: function(name) { return "Hello "+name+" how are you?"; }
}
```

And then you can call it inside the template helpers :

```
Template.GreetingsTemplate.helpers({
   sayHello: function() { return Greetings.hello('Maxence'); }
})
```

Take note of the loading order of files in Meteor, anything inside the lib folders is loaded first. If you run into problems where "Greetings" object is not defined, then its because that file was not loaded already.

Edit: 
You can reuse the same pattern for adding more functions in different files (you could use App = App || {} but it will throw error in Chrome for example).

```
App = (typeof App === 'undefined')? {} : App;
App.someFunction = function(){};
```

or even, if you use underscore.js:

```
App = (typeof App === 'undefined')? {} : App;
_.extend(App, {
  someFunction: function(){}
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks you !

Comment: also you can also do that inside a package to stay organized and export it, It's same as creating a package for facebook api and exporting FacebookApi for the api I do that for helpers/misc functions etc :) It's good pattern.

Comment: That is correct, in fact, for whole "module" of functions id recommend that. But for the "App" global object, I dont think it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since now the regular way to use the code from another file was going through a global (server and client). As Joao suggested you can make your own global `App` variable where you will store or more generically a [global `MODULE`](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) one (basically the same solution as Joao but with explanation).

But with with the arrival of ES2015 support, we will very soon be able to have an official pattern to achieve this. However as the 1.2 [does not supports yet the import/export syntax:](https://quip.com/RXFlAk9Rc2xI)

```
Note, The ES2015 module syntax (import/export) is not supported yet in Meteor 1.2.
```

If you want to start using those features earlier, I would recommend using [this package](https://atmospherejs.com/universe/modules) which is an temporary solution to fill the current import/export gap, the meteor team development are currently looking for an elegant solution to support this.