# Is it necessary to use Angular with Meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, meteor

I am angular developer. Angular is really useful for building single page applications.

I am learning Meteor which seems even more capable, especially since they have a feature called DDP which basically allows bi-directional data streaming. Meteor automatically update the DOM as well.

Could someone explain why I would want to Angular with Meteor or even use any MV* front-end framework if I were to use Meteor?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853419/why-would-i-need-angular-if-i-use-meteor

Comment: prefer that question you will get idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three basic choices for building a front-end on a Meteor application:

1. React (preferred, especially by experts)
2. Blaze (the original and the simplest for people who don't know React or Angular)
3. Angular

You can even mix these together to some extent. Sometimes a Blaze app will start growing some react offshoots for example.

Answer (score 0):

This question is inviting opinions and is likely to be deleted.

Having said that I will offer an opinion while it survives.

There is no reason not to use Angular. You need some kind of templating system, be it React, Blaze or Angular. If you know Angular it's easier to learn the Meteor bits, and not have to learn a templating language as well.

Comment: Can you please guide what is best reference where i can learn angular meteor

Comment: There is a talk from urigo that is cool, and he's the one behind the official angular integration and tutorial. https://angular-meteor.com/ https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup